# Show that $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ with $ x>0$, the improper cosine integral exists and is riemann integrable

Tags: calculus

This is the cosine integral:

$$\operatorname{Ci}(x):=-\int_x^\infty \dfrac {\cos t}t dt.$$

I need to show that the improper Riemann-Integral exists. I've searched on the web for two hours now and no one seems to have done this.

Comment: How to prove that a function $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: Upper and lower sums must converge to the same value. But I don't know where to start on this one.

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Answer (score 1):

You could perform an integration by parts for the integral
$$\int_{x}^{a}\tfrac{\cos(t)}{t} dt $$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $v(t)=\tfrac{1}{t}$, $u'(t)=\cos(t)$.
You end up with
$$\int_{x}^{a}\tfrac{\cos(t)}{t} dt =-\tfrac{1}{x}\sin(x)+\tfrac{1}{a}\sin(a)+\int_{x}^{a}\tfrac{\sin(t)}{t^{2}}dt. $$
Now it is easy to proceed, since you can pass to the limit for the first two terms and the last term $\int_{x}^{a}\tfrac{\sin(t)}{t^{2}}dt$ can be estimated using $|\cos(t)|\leq 1$. However, $x>0$ has to be assumed, since otherwise the integral is not well defined.

This is a very elementary approach, but maybe helpful.

Yours,

Alex

Comment: I just saw, Najib Idrissi already gave this hint...